# removing blinking of cursor from read only fields

Tags: jquery

I want to remove the blinking of cursor from read only fields as it gives the user experience that they can edit the text . I have written some code that is working on firefox  but not working on IE.

```
$("[readonly]").live('focus',function(e) {
    $("[readonly]").blur();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Why do you use an input if you don't allow changes or selections ?

Comment: What version of jQuery do you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set your input as disabled :

```
<input disabled>
```

If what bothers you is the grey background, you can change it using CSS :

```
input[disabled] {
  background:white; 
}
```

You can do it dynamically using

```
theInput.disabled = true;
```

Comment: I have few jsp pages with readonly input fields, I need to remove the focus from all of these readonly fields. i need to create a function that checks all the readonly fields in the html and removes the cursor.

Comment: the fields are readonly for few users and normal for another. I am not allowed to remove these fields.

Comment: @risha.9177719594 did you read my answer ? I don't propose to remove the fields.

Comment: we are not using input tags we are having struts tags for text area . can we do it using jquery selection as i have mentioned in the code above ?

Comment: we are using 1.7 version of jquery .

Comment: we are using 1.7 version of jquery

Comment: FYI, disabled inputs are not posted to the server in a form post.